# Jekyll plugin options error when trying to include options

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to use the "jekyll-minifier" plugin and have got the plugin in my config file, however, I'm having trouble with passing in options:

**Attempt 1: Doesn't work**

```
# Plugins to make everything better
plugins:
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-minifier
    preserve_php: true                # Default: false
    remove_spaces_inside_tags: true   # Default: true
    remove_multi_spaces: true         # Default: true
    remove_comments: true             # Default: true
    remove_intertag_spaces: true      # Default: false
    remove_quotes: false              # Default: false
    compress_css: false                # Default: true
    compress_javascript: false         # Default: true
    compress_json: false               # Default: true
    simple_doctype: false             # Default: false
    remove_script_attributes: false   # Default: false
    remove_style_attributes: false    # Default: false
    remove_link_attributes: false     # Default: false
    remove_form_attributes: false     # Default: false
    remove_input_attributes: false    # Default: false
    remove_javascript_protocol: false # Default: false
    remove_http_protocol: false       # Default: false
    remove_https_protocol: false      # Default: false
    preserve_line_breaks: false       # Default: false
    simple_boolean_attributes: false  # Default: false
    compress_js_templates: false      # Default: false
    preserve_patterns:                # Default: (empty)
    uglifier_args:                    # Default: (empty)
```

Where am I going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to have two entries for jekyll minifier in your _config.yml file :

one to enable the plugin :

```
plugins:
    - jekyll-minifier
```

and one to configure your plugin :

```
jekyll-minifier:
  preserve_php: true                # Default: false
  ...
```